# How to perform operations on constant variables fetched from a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, nsarray

I am making an iPhone app which uses `UIButton`s with Placeholder text on them to add and subtract pre-defined constant values; that is, if there are 3 buttons, titled A, B, and C, each of which have numerical values associated with them, I need the most simple way possible to take the values of the buttons, (which isnt explicitly shown on each button) and add them together. So if A=x and B=y, and a user pressed button A and B, and then hit an enter or calculate button, the value of A+B (x+y) would be calculated and displayed. My current plan is to use an `NSArray`, and append the values of A and B onto it, but as always, a second opinion is welcome. Hopefully this explanation was straightforward enough and easy to understand. I need this to be able to add a (theoretically) infinite number of variables. I.e: A and B multiple times, but also C, D, E...etc. This is the main reason why I was considering `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a subClass of UIButton that holds some data associated with it. Either you can set tags of your buttons and using tags as indexes take data from your NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

Put the values you want in the tag property of each button.

Comment: They will have to be integer values though.

Answer (score 0):

Will there always be two and only two numbers to add? If so, an NSArray seems like overkill. Consider that the NSArray is a pointer, and each object that the array stores will be a pointer. That would be n+1 pointers, or 3 pointers when adding 2 numbers. Why not use an integer (or float, or whatever type is appropriate) to store the total, and another integer to store the current state of the button behavior?

Let's assume you are using a controller class for the view containing your three buttons. Each of the buttons has an associated action within the controller method. These two NSUInteger variables, along with a BOOL to track whether or not the numbers will be added, can be declared in your controller class:

```
 NSUInteger total;
 NSUInteger buttonsPressed;
 BOOL adding;
```

When no buttons have been pressed, buttonsPressed would obviously equal zero. When the first button is pressed, you would do something like this:

```
  if (buttonsPressed == 0) {
      total += [[pressedButton text] intValue];
  } else {
      if (adding) {
          total += [[pressedButton text] intValue];
      } else {
          total -= [[pressedButton text] intValue];
      }
  }
  buttonsPressed++;
  if (buttonsPressed == 2) {
      // display answer and reset variables
      [answerField setText:@"%d", total];
      total = 0;
      buttonsPressed = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Technically, there would be an infinite number of items that could be added together. That's why I was thinking about an 'NSArray'. Could this code be easily adapted to work with 'NSArray'? I like the simplicity and function of it, but need it to be able to work with a large amount of numbers to be added.

Comment: Oh, I see. Could you clarify this by editing the original question?